# How can i get two of the same ImageButton methods to work?

Tags: java, android, xml, methods

```
package com.ave;

import com.ave.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Menu extends Activity{
ImageButton select;    
int isClicked = 0;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                select = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select);
        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if (isClicked == 0){
                        select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_pressed);
                        isClicked = 1;
                     }else{
                        select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select);
                        isClicked = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        ImageButton audio;   
        int isClicked1 = 0;{

        audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio);
        audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if (isClicked1 == 0){
                        audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                        isClicked1 = 1;
                     }else{
                        audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                        isClicked1 = 0;
                     }

            }});
            }
          }
```

The code itself has no errors. Same for the xml, no errors. The class has been inserted into the androidManifest file as well. However, the app closes right after the splash screen is destroyed. What am i doing wrong?

```
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/droid_background">
        <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/select"
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/audio"
        android:id="@+id/audio"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>                         '
```

=================LogCat===================

E/AndroidRuntime(  352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(  352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ave/com.ave.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at com.ave.Menu.(Menu.java:41)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)

E/AndroidRuntime(  352):    ... 11 more

================End======================

I'm aware the LogCat is flagging line 35 or the code but if i try to remove it. My second ImageButton method screws up.

Comment: I think you should move audio button code into on create method you placed it as block code.

Comment: Looks to me more like line 41 in your Menu.java. Which line is that exactly?

Comment: audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { is line 41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code I only put your block code into method. hope this will help.

```
package com.ave;

import com.ave.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Menu extends Activity {
    ImageButton select;
    int isClicked = 0;
    ImageButton audio;
    int isClicked1 = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        select = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select);
        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isClicked == 0) {
                    select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_pressed);
                    isClicked = 1;
                } else {
                    select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select);
                    isClicked = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        audio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.audio);
        audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isClicked1 == 0) {
                    audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                    isClicked1 = 1;
                } else {
                    audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                    isClicked1 = 0;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked just fine!